# How to find the maximum depth of a dictionary with lists taking a json object as input

Tags: python, arrays, json, nested-lists

I have a JSON object and I want to write a Python program that takes it as input and counts its maximum depth.

The code,

```
f = open(r"c:\python\8_DEPTH\JSON_Kino.JSON", "r")
x = f.read()

def depth(x):
    if type(x) is dict and x:
        return 1 + max(depth(x[a]) for a in x)
    if type(x) is list and x:
        return 1 + max(depth(a) for a in x)
    return 0
print(depth(x))
```

My problem is when I run the program it counts 0. Any ideas???

Comment: `x` is always a string, and that's why your function always returns 0

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a good idea to show your JSON. As Moinuddin says, you haven't parsed the JSON string to a dict or list yet, so the function just returns 0 because neither branch is true. Did you mean to use `json.loads(x)` first?

Comment: You can mark an answer as a solution, but please do not put (Solved) in the question. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def depth(myDict): 
       
    str_dic = str(myDict) 
    counter = 0
    for i in str_dic: 
        if i == "{": 
            counter += 1
    return(counter) 
   

print (depth(myDict))
```

Comment: that's a nice hack! What if one of the dicts contains a string with the `{` character in it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I also want to count the depth if there's also a list, inside a dictionary.